# MySQL: Calculations with Current/Future Row Values with different Criteria in same table?

Tags: mysql

I need this:

```
AVG(T1.CLS - T3.OPN) WHERE MIN(T1.ID) > T3.ID AND T1.YRWK = T3.YRWK
```

From this:

| ID | DT | YRWK | OPN | CLS | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 124 | 2005-09-06 18:16:00 | 200536 | 1138.50 | 1138.50 | 3 |
| 216 | 2005-09-06 21:25:00 | 200536 | 1137.75 | 1138.00 | 3 |
| 230 | 2005-09-06 21:53:00 | 200536 | 1137.50 | 1137.50 | 1 |
| 290 | 2005-09-07 00:20:00 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.50 | 3 |
| 299 | 2005-09-07 00:32:00 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.25 | 1 |
| 315 | 2005-09-07 01:02:00 | 200536 | 1138.50 | 1138.50 | 3 |
| 318 | 2005-09-07 01:05:00 | 200536 | 1138.50 | 1138.25 | 1 |
| 320 | 2005-09-07 01:07:00 | 200536 | 1138.00 | 1137.75 | 1 |
| 322 | 2005-09-07 01:09:00 | 200536 | 1138.00 | 1137.75 | 1 |
| 325 | 2005-09-07 01:12:00 | 200536 | 1138.25 | 1138.25 | 3 |

T1 is an example of a derived table where S = 1, and T3 is all rows where S = 3.

**DETAILS**:

- I need an AVG of [CLS - OPN] where only use the CLS-values from the rows where S = 1, and the OPN-values from the rows where S = 3 AND WHERE CLS-Value is the EARLIEST row AFTER the OPN-value row, AND where OPN/CLS values only occur within the same YRWK.

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

- 1137.50 - 1138.50 = -1.00 ([ID230],CLS) - ([ID124,OPN])
- 1137.50 - 1137.75 = -0.25 ([ID230],CLS - ([ID216,OPN])
- 1138.25 - 1138.25 = 0.00 ([ID299],CLS - ([ID290,OPN])
- 1138.25 - 1138.50 = -0.25 ([ID318],CLS - ([ID315,OPN])

**ANSWER = -0.375 AVG**

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1
SELECT
    A.id AS ID1,
    dt AS DT1,
    YEARWEEK(dt) AS YRWK1,
    `open` AS O1,
    `close` AS C1,
    scalper AS S1
FROM
    t_1min A
JOIN
    t_calendar B
ON
    B.id = A.id
JOIN
    t_1min_pivot C
ON
    C.id = A.id
WHERE
    scalper = 1
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T3;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T3
SELECT
    A.id AS ID3,
    dt AS DT3,
    YEARWEEK(dt) AS YRWK3,
    `open` AS O3,
    `close` AS C3,
    scalper AS S3
FROM
    t_1min A
JOIN
    t_calendar B
ON
    B.id = A.id
JOIN
    t_1min_pivot C
ON
    C.id = A.id
WHERE
    scalper = 3
;

CREATE INDEX T1ID ON T1(ID1);
CREATE INDEX T3ID ON T3(ID3);

                SELECT
                    ID3,
                    O3,
                    (

                                    SELECT
                                        MIN(ID1)
                                    FROM
                                        T1
                                    WHERE
                                        ID1 > ID3
                                ) MINID1
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            T3
                    ) S1T3
LIMIT 100
;
```

I don't think this is the most efficient way to do this, and I can't figure out how to pull the C1 and YRWK values in to achieve the final AVG calculation. I don't think a self-join would work as if you pre-filter the S=1 and S=3 into separate tables, there's no common ID to join them together on.

**INSERT CODE FOR DATA:**

```
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (124, '2005-09-06 18:16:00', 200536, 1138.50, 1138.50, 3);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (216, '2005-09-06 21:25:00', 200536, 1137.75, 1138.00, 3);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (230, '2005-09-06 21:53:00', 200536, 1137.50, 1137.50, 1);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (290, '2005-09-07 00:20:00', 200536, 1138.25, 1138.50, 3);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (299, '2005-09-07 00:32:00', 200536, 1138.25, 1138.25, 1);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (315, '2005-09-07 01:02:00', 200536, 1138.50, 1138.50, 3);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (318, '2005-09-07 01:05:00', 200536, 1138.50, 1138.25, 1);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (320, '2005-09-07 01:07:00', 200536, 1138.00, 1137.75, 1);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (322, '2005-09-07 01:09:00', 200536, 1138.00, 1137.75, 1);
INSERT INTO `t_1min` (`ID`, `DT`, `YRWK`, `O`, `C`, `S`) VALUES (325, '2005-09-07 01:12:00', 200536, 1138.25, 1138.25, 3);
```

Comment: **What version of MySQL are you using?** (this really matters to choice of solution options as v8 introduces window functions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm using 8.0.23 so Window's functions would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of MySQL supports common table expressions, then:

```
with cte as (
    select
          (select id from t_1min AS cls where cls.dt > opn.dt and cls.s = 1 and opn.s = 3 order by cls.dt limit 1) c_id
         , opn.id as o_id
    from t_1min AS opn
)
```

which produces the wanted id pairs, and from that

```
with cte as (
    select
          (select id from t_1min AS cls where cls.dt > opn.dt and cls.s = 1 and opn.s = 3 order by cls.dt limit 1) c_id
         , opn.id as o_id
    from t_1min AS opn
)

select
       cte.c_id,cte.o_id, clv.c, opv.o
     , date_format(clv.dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') c_dt
     , date_format(opv.dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') o_dt
from cte
inner join t_1min AS clv on cte.c_id = clv.id
inner join t_1min AS opv on cte.o_id = opv.id
```

which uses those id pairs to get the needed open and close values, like this:

```
+------+------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| c_id | o_id |    c    |    o    |        c_dt         |        o_dt         |
+------+------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  230 |  124 | 1137.50 | 1138.50 | 2005-09-06 21:53:00 | 2005-09-06 18:16:00 |
|  230 |  216 | 1137.50 | 1137.75 | 2005-09-06 21:53:00 | 2005-09-06 21:25:00 |
|  299 |  290 | 1138.25 | 1138.25 | 2005-09-07 00:32:00 | 2005-09-07 00:20:00 |
|  318 |  315 | 1138.25 | 1138.50 | 2005-09-07 01:05:00 | 2005-09-07 01:02:00 |
+------+------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

and, from that derived table, we can calculated the average:

```
with cte as (
    select
          (select id from t_1min AS cls where cls.dt > opn.dt and cls.s = 1 and opn.s = 3 order by cls.dt limit 1) c_id
         , opn.id as o_id
    from t_1min AS opn
)

select avg(c-o) avg_co
from (
    select
        cte.c_id,cte.o_id, clv.c, opv.o, clv.dt c_dt, opv.dt o_dt
    from cte
    inner join t_1min AS clv on cte.c_id = clv.id
    inner join t_1min AS opv on cte.o_id = opv.id
    ) AS d

+-----------+
|  avg_co   |
+-----------+
| -0.375000 |
+-----------+
```

If your version does not support cte's then just use a derived table subquery instead:

```
select avg(c-o) avg_co
from (
    select
        cte.c_id,cte.o_id, clv.c, opv.o, clv.dt c_dt, opv.dt o_dt
    from (
          select
                (select id from t_1min AS cls where cls.dt > opn.dt and cls.s = 1 and opn.s = 3 order by cls.dt limit 1) c_id
               , opn.id as o_id
          from t_1min AS opn
          ) as cte
    inner join t_1min AS clv on cte.c_id = clv.id
    inner join t_1min AS opv on cte.o_id = opv.id
    ) AS d
```

*demo @ db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a162297cb3b3d2f7572930e334f46259)*

Comment: So, I'm getting the same error as before- 'cannot reopen table: 'cls'. I've tried my original source data query as a temp table and a view- either way I get an error. How do I correct this? You can see my source table in the top of the code of my original post. Thank you!

Comment: Where is **CLS** in my code ????  I have shown you a way to use just the source table. Try it as I wrote it. If you get an error from a re-write of my code, with aliases I have no knowledge of, I'm not going to know how to fix it.  If yu are able to use CTEs then declare a CTE for whatever **cls** is it should definitely be possible to re-use a cte more than once.  if getting nowhere perhaps ADD your new code that fails to your question and then add a comment here so I will notice.

Comment: After some finageling, I got this to work! Your code was missing some criteria, and I had to move data to a formal table, but I got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: *"some finageling"* can be expected from proposed solutions as we don't have complete environments to work with - or know all requirements either.

Comment: Yup- totally get it. I was SOO FAR from your solution- there's no way I would've figured this out on my own. I also learned the value of CTEs and had some big AHA moments- so thank you for taking the time to help me!